# ignore xs:float (and other types) representation differences when comparing XML files

Tags: java, xml, junit, xmlunit

I am using [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/) for my [JUnit](http://junit.org/) tests and I would like to configure it so as to ignore differences related to alternative (but equivalent) rendering of certain types. E.g. `3.14` vs `3.140` for `xs:float` fields. I guess a full solution would require the tests to be XSD-aware so that the type of each field is known and nuanced comparisons be made in all cases (e.g. `true`/`1` for `xs:boolean` and perhaps even going so far as to account for default attribute values). At any rate, I am willing to accept workarounds so that I can get my tests running without all those false alarms.

An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (without the JUnit machinery for easier reproduction) is given below:

```
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLTestCase;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit;
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff;


class XMLTestCaseConcrete extends XMLTestCase {
}


public class FooMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String s1 = "<a>180</a>";
        String s2 = "<a>180.0</a>";
        Diff diff = XMLUnit.compareXML(s1, s2);
        System.out.printf("difference below:\n------\n%s\n------\n", diff);
        XMLTestCase xmlTest = new XMLTestCaseConcrete();
        xmlTest.assertXMLEqual(s1, s2);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Since you're producing and consuming XML already, I presume you have a library which reads/writes the XML from your own Java classes. So I think the easiest way to be flexible about the format is to parse the XML into objects and compare those objects. That's how I handle this sort of flexibility when checking JSON output. As for the XML level, the values 180 and 180.0 are technically different (i.e. 180 implies +/- 0.5 whereas 180.0 implies +/- 0.05), so it sounds like a roll-your-own situation if you absolutely need the flexibility.

Comment: Of course, it's also important to ask yourself whether you *should* allow this flexibility. If the value could be 180 in one situation and 180.0 in another, without any real difference in meaning, maybe the spec is too ambiguous?

Answer (score 4):

XMLUnit isn't schema aware, so full solution would be quite convoluted.  The way to go is to implement a custom `DifferenceListener`.

The `example` package contains a `FloatingPointTolerantDifferenceListener` that does what you need for arbitrary text nodes or attributes, but it will do so for everything that looks like a number - and it doesn't deal with any of the other schema types or default values.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I implemented this at the application layer by using (during internalization) a custom Java class to represent `xs:float` that also "remembers" the exact `String` representation it came from, so during a subsequent serialization the exact same String form is used (assuming of course it hasn't been altered by the application logic after internalization). Effectively, the only difference between this solution and a simpler and more straightforward one that treats `xs:float`s as `java.lang.String`s at the Java object layer is the additional semantical information provided by using a specialized `Float`-like type.

At any rate this solution allows me to use both the testing approach suggested by @Dave in the comments to my original question and also the more stringent test of requiring **identical** XML to be produced after a round of internalization-serialization.